# Can the standard Quantum-Mechanical Path Integral also be evaluated on a lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, path-integral, lattice-model

I have been trying to learn about lattice path integrals. Unfortunately, majority of the literature on this topic is in regard to Lattice Quantum Field Theory and Lattice Quantum Chromodynamics. That is fine, however what I desire is literature on evaluating plain, standard quantum-mechanical path integrals on a discrete spatial-lattice, ideally in continuous-time. This could be a simple chain of atoms or a crystal lattice, but it would be a system where the lattice actually exists and is not just used as a regularisation tool for a continuum quantum field theory.

For example, what is the "path integral" (I imagine this would instead be a summation now instead of an "integral") for a free particle on a lattice? Can it be evaluated in that it has a closed-form solution? Even if an ideal closed-form expression cannot be obtained, how far can one go? (E.g. reduce to discrete Gauss-sum or a Jacobi-theta function) In the continuum case, this is just a Gaussian functional integral, which results in a Gaussian. What would it be if space is discretised?

Then what is the path integral for a harmonic oscillator on a lattice? What if you add a force term? What about a general quadratic Lagrangian?

I have struggled to find mention of these problems in the literature. The standard approach is to introduce the typical time-sliced path integral derivation, and then jump to the Klein-Gordon equation. Are there any resources that do not jump to field theory and instead just investigate these lattice problems for simple quantum mechanical toy models?

As a slight aside, I was wondering also if you could start from a typical continuum space path integral, for say a free particle, and add a delta-functional constraint to restrict the continuous path to lattice sites? This would enter the action then as a Lagrangian multiplier and may be evaluable.

Thanks!

Comment: I did not read the question fully, but the first thing that popped into my mind on reading the question is the book https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-01850-3_1. Will try to answer the complete question more precisely in a while. Fortunately, the book is also free to download, as opposed to the extremely irritating case of books behind a paywall :)

Comment: @VaibhavK Thanks for your quick response! :) That's a good textbook, but again focuses on the field-theory case. It introduced the standard quantum mechanical path integral then jumps into Scalar Field theories and beyond and putting them on a lattice. I was wondering if there're resources that look at *path* integrals on a lattice rather than *field* integrals on a lattice?